# CSS3 Transform objects position without Transition applied

Tags: animation, css, transform, transition

I'm looking for a simple way to take an object and transform its rotateY property without it animating to its pre-set transition.

It would look a little like:

```
$(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
$(this).css("-webkit-transition","10s");
```

then later in the code

```
$(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(0)");
$(this).css("-webkit-transition","0");
```

But the above doesn't quite work for me due to the fact that it needs to set and reset the transitions animation timing.

I need a solution that simply takes the object from point a to b without any fuss. I cant seem to find a way to set the rotateY property without going through the transition/transform prefix.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: Coud you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve? I've made a fiddle that kind of shows what you've mentioned http://jsfiddle.net/sambeckhamdesign/P2YTS/14/

Answer (score 1):

What you need sounds like CSS3 animations.

So... in your case because you want the animation to be in it's finished point, your code would look like this

```
$(this).css("-webkit-animation", "someanimation 10s forwards");
```

The forwards property in a CSS3 animation assures that the end point in your animation is a permanent rendered style, so the animation will stay in its end state until you unload the page.

In your CSS, you would have to add

```
@-webkit-keyframes someanimation { <br />
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);} <br />
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);} <br />
}
```

This code above isn't particular to any class or ID. It's it's own section.

Here's some documentation on CSS3 animations [W3C Standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/)

And here's an article [Smashing Mag](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-css3-keyframe-animations/)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what you want -

http://jsfiddle.net/rq0574yz/2/

I have added a 'S' and set `border-right: 5px solid red`, so that you can see that it actually comes back to its initial position without transition.
Actually it comes with transition but in the keyframe I have shortened the particular transition duration to few milliseconds (20 milliseconds) so that user does not recognize and thinks it rotated back in no time.

Comment: I have not used vendor prefixes such as -webkit-, -ms- or -o-, Without vendor prefixes, in latest Mozilla Firefox the animation works as it should. But if you have another browser, then you have to add those vendor prefixes to view the animation the way you want.

That's why I like Mozilla.

Comment: Also you can change the various timings easily by just adjusting the % and overall animation duration.